# Using Editor template for varying display

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have to display my decimal as 00.00.  I have the following EditorTemplate

```
 @model Decimal?

@if (Model.HasValue)
{
   @Model.Value.ToString("00.00");
 }
```

I have to display the decimal in a textbox and label as well.  How can I use the above Template  to display the following in the wanted format.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>@item.Price)
 @Html.LabelFor(m=>@item.Price)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`[DisplayFormat]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx) attribute on your model:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:00.00}", NullDisplayText = "")]
public decimal? Price { get; set; }
```

and then to display:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Price)
```

and to edit:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Price)
```

Comment: With @EditorFor it`s stil displaying as a label not as a textbox

Comment: @user281180, that's probably because you have some custom editor template for the decimal type, haven't you?

Answer (score 0):

In your template you can use

```
@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("00.00") : String.Empty))
```

or

```
@if (Model.HasValue) {
  @Model.Value.ToString("00.00");
  @Html.TextBox("", Model.Value.ToString("00.00"))
}
```

Then in your view use

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Price)%>
```

Comment: With the code i`ve provided, I could do it well for Textbox.  Bit how to do that with labelFor and TexboxFor?

Comment: Use @Html.EditorFor() to display the template in your view

Answer (score 0):

create a 
Decimal.ascx under Views\Shared\EditorTemplates folder

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<decimal?>" %>
<% 
Html.LabelFor(m => m);
Html.TextBox (ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(string.Empty),
```

Model.HasValue ?
Model.Value.ToString("00.00") : "00.00", 
new {readonly = "readonly"})
    %>

if all you need is displaying it, in that case switch Editor for Display (DisplayTemplates, DisplayFor, etc)
readonly attribute is to make the textbox read-only (un-editable)